# Removing backslashes in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my string, `tel:\\99999999999`. Everytime I try to open it, it comes with a single back slash like `\99999999999`.

How do I remove both the back slashes so that the phone number becomes `99999999999`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tel = 'tel:\\99999999999';
tel = tel.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/4yZur/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var telString = telString.replace("tel:\\\\","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
stringPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
```